# I can not find user by email (parse.com)

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform

I have a class "User". And i have user with email "'qq@qq.qq"

I did that query:

```
var UserSearch = Parse.Object.extend("User");
var query = new Parse.Query(UserSearch);
query.equalTo('email', 'qq@qq.qq');
query.first({
  success: function(object) {
    console.log('success');
    console.log(object);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

And received an empty object.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can also use this regex to check if a string is a valid email: 
`^[A-Za-z0-9._]+@[A-Za-z0-9._]+\.[A-Za-z]+$`

Comment: how this can help me?

Comment: `emailToCheck.match(/^[A-Za-z0-9._]+@[A-Za-z0-9._]+\.[A-Za-z]+$/)`. Put that into `if`.

Comment: I tried to look for another field and got the same result.

Comment: I mean another field is not email

Comment: are you sure? This snippet returns an array if there's a match, and `null` otherwise.

Comment: var UserSearch = Parse.Object.extend("User");
            var query = new Parse.Query(UserSearch);
            query.equalTo('passwordReset', $stateParams.secret);
            query.first({
                success: function(objectUser) {
                    console.log('success');
                    console.log(objectUser);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                }
            });


Console:

success
undefined

Comment: Problem not in the email. Problem in the "query.equalTo" parameter.

Comment: I need receive the user object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of two issues here.  Either you're using the special class Users, which does not have a string form of "User", or you do not have permission to read the object.  Really, other users should not be able to query the Users class.  It should be funneled through a Cloud Function where you can handle the security and only return certain data.

Try this first:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo('email','qq@qqq.com');
query.first().then(function(user) {
  console.log(user);
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Or, use a cloud function, which can query with the master key:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('getUserByEmail', function(request, response) {
  var email = request.params.email;
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.equalTo('email', email);
  query.first({ useMasterKey: true }).then(function(user) {
    response.success(user.get('username'));
  }, function(err) {
    response.error(err);
  });
});
```

Which is run via JavaScript as:

```
Parse.Cloud.run('getUserByEmail', {email:'qq@qqq.com'}).then(function(username) {
  console.log(username);
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions

https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#cloudfunctions

Comment: Also worth noting the issue with case sensitivity, if the User was created with email "QQ@qqq.com" and you search for "qq@qqq.com" you won't find a match. Either force to lowercase on create or create a lowercase search field using beforeSave.